# hyperlinking table in catalyst

Tags: catalyst, template-toolkit

I have a web page developed in Catalyst MVC framework. I am using Template Toolkit for my views. I have two tables in one of my web page. I want to hyperlink one table to the other and open the other table (i.e. linked table) in a new tab or in the same page using ajax.

I am very new to Catalyst as well as Template Toolkit. I kindly request you to help me in understanding how do I make it possible? Is it possible to call a template within a template? If so how do I achieve it?

I would be grateful to accept any other suggestions apart from above mentioned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling template from the other template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343073/calling-template-from-the-other-template)

Answer (score 1):

Template Toolkit and Ajax does not naturally go together. Template Toolkit is a server side technology and Ajax is mix of JavaScript and a web browser API called XMLHttpRequest.

Catalyst can respond to Ajax requests by returning a compiled `.tt`-template. Template Toolkit does not care about what Catalyst is doing.

The magic is in the mix of Catalyst, Template Toolkit and Ajax. Normally this is done, as in your case, that a link in `#table1` subscribes to a JavaScript event that fetches `#table2`. `#table2` can be a Catalyst action (`/my_app/tables/2`) which stashes data and compiles a `.tt`-template.

Outside `#table1` we have a `#table_wrapper`.

```
# jQuery
$('#table1 .next').click(function () {
    $('#table_wrapper').load('/my_app/tables/2');
});
```

Does this make sense to you? I can follow up if you need more input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I am naive to the field of programming,I request you to elaborate more on what you have explained i.e what is #table_wrapper? My table2 actually gets dynamically filled on click on table1. With your code I am getting a empty table..